# Is there a way to enable ReplicationConfiguration for AWS S3 Replication management using s3.putbucketreplication API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to enable replication configuration via the s3.putbucketreplication() api. I am getting "**InvalidRequest: Priority cannot be used for this version of Cross Region Replication configuration schema. Please refer to S3 Developer Guide for more information.**" error. What does this mean?

```
var params = {
 Bucket: "428096-jwtuseragent-data-lab",
 ReplicationConfiguration: {
    Role: "arn:aws:iam::315327487940:role/S3BatchJobRole",
    Rules: [ Destination: {
                    Bucket: "arn:aws:s3:::428096-jwtuseragent-details-lab",
                    ReplicationTime: {
                        Status: "Enabled",
                        Time: {
                            Minutes: 15
                        }
                    },
                    Metrics: {
                        Status: "Enabled",
                        EventThreshold: {
                            Minutes: 15
                        }
                    }

                },                  
                ID: "folder",
                DeleteMarkerReplication:{
                      Status: "Disabled"
                    },
                Prefix: "folder1/",
                    Priority: 2,
                Status: "Enabled"
            }]
}}
```

This is my params.
Please help

Comment: Could you format your code?

Comment: Hi @jellycsc, please check now

Answer (score 15):

S3 supports two versions of replication configuration, V1 and V2. The method of defining which one you want to use is quite obscure: You signal use of V2 by including field *Filter* in the rule. Conversely, if you do not include *Filter*, V1 is assumed. *Priority* field is only available in V2, so if you want to use it (or *ReplicationTime* time for that matter), you need to include *Filter*.

You can convert your request to V2 by replacing entry `Prefix: "folder1/"` with `Filter: { Prefix: "folder1/" }`.

The difference between V1 and V2 and how to create requests using either is described, unfortunately very unclearly, in AWS documentation article [Replication Configuration Overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-add-config.html)