# ReplicationTime cannot be used for this version of the replication configuration schema

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am trying to get S3 Replication working via AWS CDK. I am using https://github.com/rogerchi/cdk-s3-bucketreplication/blob/main/src/index.ts as a starting point and it does create a replication rule. However there are some issues when trying to make it specific the case i want to setup.

When adding RTC (Replication Time Control)

```
sourceBucket.replicationConfiguration = {
      role: replicationRole.roleArn,
      rules: [
        {
          destination: {
            storageClass: ReplicationDestinationStorageClass.STANDARD_IA,
            bucket: destinationBucket.bucketArn,
            metrics: {
              status: "Enabled",
              eventThreshold: {
                minutes: 15,
              },
            },
            replicationTime: {
              status: "Enabled",
              time: {
                minutes: 15,
              },
            },
          },
          status: ReplicationRuleStatus.ENABLED,
        },
      ],
    };
```

I get the following error....

```
ReplicationTime cannot be used for this version of the replication configuration schema.
```

Also, i do not wish to use a prefix but want the rule scope to be "This rule applies to all objects in the bucket". As per the console setting below. The above approach appears to create a configuration that 'should' have a prefix. i.e. Looking at the created rule it appears to have "Limit the scope of this rule using one or more filters" selected by default.

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Terraform v1.3.2 with aws v4.22.0 the sintax that worked for me is the following:

```
filter {
  and {
    tags = {}
  }
}
```

which will allow you to configure RTC, DeleteMarker, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Terraform and had to add this:

```
        filter {
          tags = {}
        }
```

I got the hint from here: [Is there a way to enable ReplicationConfiguration for AWS S3 Replication management using s3.putbucketreplication API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875010/is-there-a-way-to-enable-replicationconfiguration-for-aws-s3-replication-managem) which points to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-add-config.html#replication-config-optional-filter which (not very clearly) indicates that you need to use the API V2 for replication to work:

```
Replication configuration XML V2 includes the Filter element for rules.
```

As you want all objects (as did I) there is also:

```
If you specify a rule with an empty filter tag your rule will apply to all objects in your bucket.
```